# C++ unusing using

Tags: c++, namespaces, using, short

Can I undo a command `using`?

Example code of what I was thinking:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace one {
    void write() {
        cout << "write:one" << endl;
    }
}

namespace two {
    void write() {
        cout << "write:two" << endl;
    }
}

void write() {
    cout << "write:write" << endl;
}

int main() {
    one::write();
    two::write();
    using one::write;
    write();    //And it's called from namespace one witch is correct
                //but now i want to call a global method and how i can do that.
    return 0;
}
```

I want to switch from calling one to global. Can I do this? If so, how?

Comment: I removed the BASIC tag because there's no any relation to this topic and the BASIC programming language giving false-positives on search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot undo a `using` directive. But you can use a name from the global namespace with `::`. For example,

```
::write();
```